# If statement do not work with modulo. Can't get the console.log() to write out anything. I am using a const with a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, constants, modulo

My task is like this:

You will see the array 'numbers'. Use a for loop to go through that array. For each element in the array, print the number to the console using console.log. If the number is divisible by 3, instead of the number print the string 'apple' to the console. Should the number be divisible by 5, print the string 'cake' to the console instead of the number.

In the first task, I used a for loop to show every number from 1-20, so I can't seem to understand why I can't get this to work. I am maybe thinking I have to implement a new for loop in this task too.

My code is like this:

```
console.log('PART 3')
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

if (numbers % 3){
    console.log('eple');
}

else if(numbers % 5){
    console.log('kake');
}
```

Comment: `numbers % 3` doesn't make sense since `numbers` is an array

Comment: *'Use a for loop to go through that array'* is the key part you're missing

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use modulo (Reminder Operator `%`) on an array.
You're missing a `for` loop (as stated by the task requirement) in order to iterate over its values:

```js
console.log('PART 3')
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

for (let number of numbers) {
  if (number % 3){
      console.log(number + ' eple');
  }

  else if(number % 5){
      console.log(number + ' kake');
  }
}
```

Comment: "_If the number is divisible by 3, print 'apple'_" A number is divisible by 3 when `number % 3 === 0`.

Comment: You can actually use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) ([it's not modulo in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder#description)) on an array, but only if the default coercion results in a meaningful value `[2] % 2 === 0`

Comment: Using `number % 3` on its own won't result in the correct logic

Comment: I can't get any value out, I understand the code. My problem is that I can't seem to understand what's wrong, added a for loop now but it still won't write out the words. It stops at Part 3.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out if a number is a factor of another number:

```js
number % 3 === 0
```

That translates as: *If a number divided by 3 has a remainder of 0...*

You don't even have a `for` loop

```js
for (let i=0; i < array.length; i++) {...}
```

There are 3 expressions of a `for` loop statement

| Expression | Example | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Initial | ``` let i=0 ``` | Define variable at the beginning |
| Condition | ``` i < array.length ``` | When variable no longer less than the quantity of elements within the array stop loop |
| Increment | ``` i++ ``` | Variable increments by 1 |

Flow control statements can be only in a certain order:

```js
if (a > b) {...}
// OR
if (a > b) {...}
else {...}
// OR
if (a > b) {...}
else if (a === b) {...}
// ...more else if(...){...} if required
else {...}
```

Never do this

```js
if (a > b) {...}
else if (a === b) {...}
```

```js
// This will create an array of 1 - 20 programatically
const array = [...Array(20)].map((_, i) => i + 1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let number = array[i];
  if (number % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("APPLE");
  } else if (number % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("CAKE");
  } else {
    console.log(number);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        console.log('PART 3')
    const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
    const output = [];
    
    for(i=numbers[0];i<=numbers.length;i++){
     if(numbers[i]%3==0 && numbers[i]%5==0){
        output.push(numbers[i] + " :Apple, Cake")
         console.log(output);
     }
      else if(numbers[i]%5==0){
        output.push(numbers[i] + " :Cake")
          console.log(output);
      }
    else if(numbers[i]%3==0){
       output.push(numbers[i] + " :Apple")
        console.log(output);
      }
     }
```

Comment: _"i don't know if this will answer your question"_ - sadly it doesn't answer the question.